# Calling from Main()

Tags: c#, class, program-entry-point

I have the problem that I am declaring a public class and struct and then have to run a function from my main and cannot declare the variables inside the class and struct from main. Because of this the function will not work due to the "No overload for method" error. How would I go about fixing this? I feel as though I am missing something extremely simple but cannot see it.

Thanks in advance. If you would like any further information to help me then do not hesitate to ask.

```
 public struct CellReference
    {
        private int CNorth, CEast;

        public int CellsNorth
        {
            get
            {
                return CellsNorth;
            }
            set
            {
                CNorth = value;
            }
        }

        public int CellsEast
        {
            get
            {
                return CellsEast;
            }
            set
            {
                CEast = value;
            }
        }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Piece black1, black2, black3, black4, black5, black6, black7, black8, black9, black10, black11, black12, white1, white2, white3, white4, white5, white6, white7, white8, white9, white10, white11, white12;


        StartGame();
        Console.ReadKey();


    }


    public class Piece
    {
        public CellReference Location;
        public bool isBlack;
        public bool isKing;

    }
```

Basically I can't initialize some variables which StartGame() needs.

Well StartGames as so:

```
static void StartGame(ref int CNorth, ref int CEast, ref bool isKing, ref bool isBlack, ref int CellsEast, ref int CellsNorth, ref Piece black1, ref Piece black2, ref Piece black3, ref Piece black4, ref Piece black5, ref Piece black6, ref Piece black7, ref Piece black8, ref Piece black9, ref Piece black10, ref Piece black11, ref Piece black12, ref Piece white1, ref Piece white2, ref Piece white3, ref Piece white4, ref Piece white5, ref Piece white6, ref Piece white7, ref Piece white8, ref Piece white9, ref Piece white10, ref Piece white11, ref Piece white12)
```

However if I call StartGame() in main, if I put all the references in it doesn't work since they are not in Main.

Comment: Could you please post your code in order to clarify your question?

Comment: `If you would like any further information to help me then do not hesitate to ask.` - yes, your sample source code so that we could see what might be wrong with it.

Comment: post code, accept a solution. Simple SO rule!

Comment: If `StartGame` needs some variables shouldn't you pass them to it?

Comment: Also I see the error in `CellReference` properties - you try to return itself rather then corresponding `CNorth, CEast` values.

Comment: You need to post complete code that reproduces the error. How is `StartGame()` defined? Which line is the error on?

Comment: I am guessing you declared all of those inside the Program class. Such that Piece and CellReference are inner struct and class. Cut and paste the Piece black1, black2 etc just above the static void main line and try running again?

Comment: Maybe you want pass some vars to StartGame but just declared the StartGame method without parameters? This will cause 'no overload' error.

Comment: @Jake I did so, but now it comes up with the error that "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property".

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks:

**The error:**

> No overload for method 'Main' takes 0 arguments

This error occurs because you are calling the method `StartGame` without argument while is is expecting an huge list of arguments. To fix the problem, specify arguments to your method ;)

**The accessors:**

The first time you'll try to get the value of `CellReference.CellsEast` or `CellReference.CellsNorth`, you'll have a `StackOverflowException` because the accessor is calling itself. To fix that problem, you can rewrite the `struct` like this:

```
public struct CellReference
{
    public int CellsNorth
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public int CellsEast
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

**The `StartGame` signature:**

**19** arguments, it is too much!!! Please use an `Array` of Pieces. I'd wrote this kind of code:

```
void Main()
{
    var pieces= new Piece[] 
    { 
        new Piece(1), 
        new Piece(2) 
    };
    StartGame(array);
}

private void StartGame(Piece[] pieces)
{
    /* Do your work*/
}

class Piece
{
    public Piece(int i)
    {
        this.Value = i;
    }
    private int Value { get; set; }
}
```

**The `ref` keyword:**

Why are you using the keyword `ref`? Do you want the `StartGame` modifies your arguments that you'll use in the `Main` method?

I'd created a class that contains an array of pieces with methods to modify them. And if you need to get the values of the pieces, I'd created getters.

**Pascal case for you fields:**

Usually, we use Camel case for the field (or we prefix with "`_`" or "`m_`") and Pascal Case for the properties, classes and methods. If everything is in Pascal Case, you don't really know what your are using. It is not mandatory but, it is a good practice rule.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why people are not answering is because you demostrate a lack of basic programming concepts that it becomes hard for people to explain to you clearly your problem. @jibedoubleve has highlight many of them. I suggest you pick up a C# beginner book to read to gain more understanding.

IMHO, I think the fundamental issue you have is understanding a C# program entry point and OOP concepts. So here is my attempt to explain in code:

```
public static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var game = new Game();
        game.StartGame();
    }
}

public class Game
{
    Piece black1, black2, black3,
    black4, black5, black6, black7, 
    black8, black9, black10, black11,
    black12, white1, white2, white3,
    white4, white5, white6, white7,
    white8, white9, white10, white11, white12;

    public struct CellReference
    {
        public int CellsNorth;

        public int CellsEast;
    }

    public class Piece
    {
        public CellReference Location
        public bool isBlack;
        public bool isKing;
    }

    public StartGame()
    {
        // play game logic here
    }
}
```

The auto-generated Program class handles Application level issues such as creating window and checking application run priviledges.

The Main() function is the program entry point. You create a Game object to manipulate the pieces and logic. Notice that Program class should not have a StartGame() method, instead, it is the Game object that knows how to start a game.